# Query to azure table does not return any data

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Following is the code used to fetch data from azure table:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
 CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
 TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
 CloudTableQuery<Customer> partitionQuery =
                (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<Customer>("Customer")
                 select e).AsTableServiceQuery<Customer>();

// Loop through the results, displaying information about the entity
   foreach (Customer entity in partitionQuery)
   {
        CustomerList.Add(entity);
   }
```

Everything was working fine. Suddenly I observed that, above call does not return anything.
It is able to get the ServiceContext. And I tried to troubleshoot using `"Fidler"` tool. Actually data is coming from the cloud table (which I saw in query response in Fidler). But when I iterate `"partitionQuery"` object, it returns with no data. Same code works with other machines. The Azure SDK used is same in other machines also. Can anyone help on this? Thanks.

**Update:** Now I am using new version of Azure SDK. (Oct 2012) Can this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same problem.  When I specify a partition key (or any other query), it works just fine.

```
rangeQuery = new TableQuery<PhotoEvent>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForBool("active", QueryComparisons.Equal, true));
```

Comment: Is it because of the version change?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the October 2012 Azure SDK , you want to change :

```
TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();

CloudTableQuery<Customer> partitionQuery = (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<Customer>("Customer")
select e).AsTableServiceQuery<Customer>();
```

to

```
TableServiceContext serviceContext = tableClient.GetTableServiceContext();

TableServiceQuery<Customer > partitionQuery = (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<Customer>(“Customer”)
                                                               select e).AsTableServiceQuery(serviceContext);
```

Note: see a [more detailed list of breaking change](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx).

Also, please make sure you have included the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DataServices` namespace.

If you are still observing an unexpected behavior, please provide a fiddler trace (through email) so that we can investigate this further.